# What is the most responsible way to visualise non-response / NA data in a plot?

Tags: accuracy, ggplot2

I'm working on plotting census data, which has a fairly high non-response rate for some questions (5% or higher). This could actually shift the way we interpret the results in quite significant ways (e.g. there are more non-responses than there are answers for some of the categories).

It doesn't seem accurate to represent non-responses as just another bar among many other bars, so I'm searching for an alternative way to represent this information to a viewing audience. What is the best way to represent the way that this non-data might impact how we should interpret the results? I could simply put a non-response = xx line as an annotation at the bottom of my plot. But this could be easily missed by a viewer - has anyone tried experimenting with modifying bars or some other more active annotation?

The most relevant way to do this is using bars/grouped bars with census data. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(nomisr) # quickly grab census data from UK data clearinghouse nomis
z <- nomis_get_data(id = "NM_529_1", time = "latest", geography = "TYPE499", measures=c(20301))
uk_census_2011_religion <- filter(z, GEOGRAPHY_NAME=="England and Wales" & RURAL_URBAN_NAME=="Total" & C_RELPUK11_NAME != "All categories: Religion")
uk_census_2011_religion <- select(uk_census_2011_religion, C_RELPUK11_NAME, OBS_VALUE)
ggplot(uk_census_2011_religion, aes(x = C_RELPUK11_NAME, y = OBS_VALUE)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

And a visualisation sample:

[image: bar chart]

Comment: It would help to know what kind of graphical representation you are thinking of. You mention bars ?

Comment: I've just added a reproducible example, which produces an (ugly) bar chart

Comment: Your example is no doubt reproducible by R users. Everybody else, and indeed everybody, would benefit from seeing the result please.

Comment: Fair point - have added a png output which includes "Religion not stated" as a column among the others

Comment: Why does that seem inaccurate to you?

Comment: Thanks. I would (1) rotate the plot to horizontal bars (2) colour not stated differently (3) think about separating it by a gap from other bars (4) not use alphabetical order, but sort on frequency (yet leaving not stated out of that sequence) (5) remove ticks on categorical axis.

Comment: Well, thinking through the way a respondent might interact with the instrument, there are a wide range of reasons they might choose not to respond. But it is at least somewhat likely that a non-response may be because a person doesn't fell comfortable disclosing the information regardless of anonymity protocols etc. In this particular case, minority religious groups can underidentify in census instruments, so it's highly likely that non response is actually concealing data which could be attributed to other columns.

Comment: So my concern is that NA is potentially part of the margin of error in interpreting a response, and not a separate category per se.

Comment: England and Wales 2011, so I am a data point in one of those bars. Given the option to say "no religion", and on other grounds. I agree strongly, that no assumptions can be made safely about "not stated".

Comment: You say "there are more non-responses than there are answers for some of the categories" meaning that for each religion, people can chose not to state if they are from this specific religion ? Because it looks to me that the choices are between the religions represented here and "no religion" and non response. What exactly was the question ?

Comment: @CaroZ  It's been a while, but IIRC no religion was a category you could choose and not stated is analysts' count of people who ignored the question, which was certainly not compulsory.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - the question was: "What is your religion?" but respondents were only allowed to choose a single response (so hybrid responses such as Pagan + Christian weren't allowed and might have been represented in NA category). Responses included "no religion" but also response was not mandatory, so there is an additional batch of NA data (5-6% of responses). Given that some of the categories (as seen in the chart) are quite low, e.g. Jewish and Buddhist are < 1%, this requires some navigation...

Comment: The "other religion" category also included quite a lot of subcatories (e.g. spiritual, hybrid, etc.) but was a fill-in, so data is quite messy.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see anything wrong with your representation, I would simply be more precise in what "religion not stated" means. I would call it "no answer" instead and put this category last. I would reorder the religions (including "no religion" by frequency, as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The barplot is okay but makes it hard to read off the percentages, esp. for the smaller categories.

I think a table works better.

```
  Christian        59.3
  No religion      25.1
  Other religion    8.4     Muslim     4.8
                            Hindu      1.5
                            Sikh       0.8
                            Jewish     0.5
                            Buddhist   0.4
                            Other      0.4
  No response       7.2
```

If you prefer a plot instead, one option is a stacked barplot though it would take care to position the labels of the minor categories so that they are readable.

I ended up making two stacked barplots: one barplot for the major categories where I put religions other than Christianity under a single label, "Other religion", and another barplot for the minor categories on their own.

[image]
[image]